# No virtual method Boolean call-mutableStateOf

Tags: kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform, mutablestateof

Get the next error, when I try to create a `properties` variable in a `actual fun`

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
> Boolean$arg-2$call-$init$$arg-0$call-mutableStateOf$fun-$anonymous$$arg-0$call-remember$val-properties$delegate$fun-GoogleMaps()Z
> in class Lcom/mandarine/fiveplus/util/LiveLiterals$GoogleMapsKt; or
> its super classes (declaration of
> 'com.mandarine.fiveplus.util.LiveLiterals$GoogleMapsKt' appears in
> /data/data/com.mandarine.fiveplus.android/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes7.dex)
> at
> com.mandarine.fiveplus.util.GoogleMapsKt.GoogleMaps(GoogleMaps.kt:45)

Also here is my fun:

```
@Composable
actual fun GoogleMaps(
    modifier: Modifier,
    isControlsVisible: Boolean,
    onMarkerClick: ((MapMarker) -> Unit)?,
    onMapClick: ((LatLong) -> Unit)?,
    onMapLongClick: ((LatLong) -> Unit)?,
    markers: List<MapMarker>?,
    cameraPosition: CameraPosition?,
    cameraPositionLatLongBounds: CameraPositionLatLongBounds?,
    polyLine: List<LatLong>?
) {
    val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState()
    val uiSettings by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            MapUiSettings()
        )
    }
    val properties by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            MapProperties(
                isMyLocationEnabled = true,
                minZoomPreference = 10f,
                maxZoomPreference = 20f,
            )
        )
    }

    LaunchedEffect(cameraPosition) {
        cameraPosition?.let { cameraPosition ->
            CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                LatLng(
                    cameraPosition.target.latitude,
                    cameraPosition.target.longitude
                ),
                cameraPosition.zoom
            )
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(cameraPositionLatLongBounds) {
        cameraPositionLatLongBounds?.let {

            val latLngBounds = LatLngBounds.builder().apply {
                it.coordinates.forEach { latLong ->
                    include(LatLng(latLong.latitude, latLong.longitude))
                }
            }.build()

            cameraPositionState.move(
                CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds, it.padding)
            )
        }
    }

    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        GoogleMap(
            cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
            modifier = modifier,
            uiSettings = uiSettings,
            properties = properties,
            onMapClick = { latLng: LatLng ->
                onMapClick?.let { nativeFun ->
                    nativeFun(LatLong(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude))
                }
            },

            ) {
            markers?.forEach { marker ->
                Marker(
                    state = rememberMarkerState(
                        key = marker.key,
                        position = LatLng(marker.position.latitude, marker.position.longitude)
                    ),
                    alpha = marker.alpha,
                    title = marker.title
                )
            }

            polyLine?.let { polyLine ->
                Polyline(
                    points = List(polyLine.size) {
                        val latLong = polyLine[it]
                        LatLng(latLong.latitude, latLong.longitude)
                    },
                    color = Color(0XFF1572D5),
                    width = 16f
                )
                Polyline(
                    points = List(polyLine.size) {
                        val latLong = polyLine[it]
                        LatLng(latLong.latitude, latLong.longitude)
                    },
                    color = Color(0XFF00AFFE),
                    width = 8f
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but the error refers to my `expect function`:

```
@Suppress("NO_ACTUAL_FOR_EXPECT")
@Composable
expect fun GoogleMaps(
    modifier: Modifier,
    isControlsVisible: Boolean = true,
    onMarkerClick: ((MapMarker) -> Unit)? = {},
    onMapClick: ((LatLong) -> Unit)? = {},
    onMapLongClick: ((LatLong) -> Unit)? = {},
    markers: List<MapMarker>? = null,
    cameraPosition: CameraPosition? = null,
    cameraPositionLatLongBounds: CameraPositionLatLongBounds? = null,
    polyLine: List<LatLong>? = null
)
```

Comment: Hello! Can you please provide more context or details as to what you're trying to do here and what's wrong?